# Copy information from one pdf to another pragmatically

Tags: java, itext

I am having a pdf with a certain layout and I want to take the information from there and place it into a new pdf with an updated layout. What I am thinking as the correct course of action is to map the elements of the first pdf, find the elements that I need and then paste them into the new pdf.

I have read the resources from the itextpdf site but I can not properly piece them together.

Any study materials or how-to would be really helpful. Thanks

Edit 1: I have done something like that

```
 val reader = PdfReader(path)

        val size = reader.numberOfPages

        for (i in 1..size) {
            val content = reader.getPageContent(i)
            println(content?.contentToString())
        }
```

which of course is not working.

Comment: When you say you want to *"take the information"*, do you merely mean the plain text? Or formatted text (with special fonts or colors)? Or tabular data? And how do you want to place it in the new layout? Re-flown to match different widths and sizes? As an exact copy of the original? Somehow else?

Comment: Valid questions, sorry for not clarifying. https://imgur.com/2uV7Q6g This is the layout of the pdf1 (months grid) and I want to take the information of each cell and paste it in a similar grid on pdf2. @mkl

Comment: Are the cell positions and sizes constant or may they change?

Comment: They are constant, both the origin cells and the destination ones @mkl

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I would structure the program as follows:

- read all the required elements in your source document.
- store the data in some kind of internal storage object
- write the stored data into a new document

Your storage object could look like this:

```
public class FieldContainer {
    public String field1;
    public String field2;
    // ...
}
```

Comment: I ended up doing exactly that but forgot to post it here. Thanks a lot, later this day I will post the complete solution.